# WSO2 EI 6.5 0- Changing port - Service call not happen

Tags: wso2, scheduled-tasks, offset, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

In WSO2 EI 6.5.0 , port offset has been done  `<Offset>3</Offset>` in the below path `<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml.`

I have designed Task scheduler to call proxy service.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<task class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector" group="synapse.simple.quartz" name="EmailTicketingScheduler" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <trigger interval="60"/>
    <property name="proxyName" value="EmailTicket_ConnectMSOutlook_Proxy" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
    <property name="soapAction" value="urn:mediate" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
    <property name="message" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks">
        <root xmlns=""/>
    </property>
    <property name="injectTo" value="proxy" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
</task>
```

When Jobs running, Scheduler failed to call proxy even this proxy is available in WSO2 EI Server due to this port offset change.

Getting below ERROR:

```
Connection refused or failed for: localhost/127.0.0.1:8280
```

What are all the other configuration needs to be enabled/changed in WSo2 EI after changing port offset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested with a simple proxy service and the same schedule task. I did not have any issues with invoking the proxy service from the schedule task when I configure an offset. Since there is a service trying to connect to 8280 port, can you check if there are any internal calls from the proxy service to port 8280.

Comment: Yes , As you said there is one endpoint which has 8280 port. Thanks for your suggestion